# Program execute at a certain time

Tags: c, winapi, time

Alright so my question is, how can I make a program that basically executes the rest of the program at for example 12pm. For example some non realistic code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

     Get_time() //Gets system time

     if(time() == 254pm ){ //if time is 2:54pm

             printf("Time: 2:54pm\n");
         }

      else printf("Program can not execute at this time.\n");

      return 0;
 }
```

Does anyone know how I can do something similar?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?

Comment: Nope, just need my program to execute the rest of the code at a certain time.. For windows.

Comment: Or [Windows Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569), since this specifically was tagged `winapi`. The `Scheduler API` is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383608(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`localtime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/) to get the current time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    // Get system time
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    // Check
    if(timeinfo->tm_hour == 14 && timeinfo->tm_min == 54)
    {
        printf("Time: 2:54pm\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do that but the important part is to keep CPU free. otherwise with an infinite loop, you would spend a lot of resources. I would suggest using a `Sleep()` or a smart wait mechanism like boost library has. `Sleep()` is a much simpler for you and all you need is to include `windows.h`

A sample code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main() {
    int timeDelta = ...; // calculate time delta in miliseconds here (12 PM today - now)
    Sleep(timeDelta);
    // execute your code here
}
```